# "Живущий" и "проживающий"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Есть ли разница между словами "живущий" и "проживающий" и когда что лучше употреблять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разумеется есть. Определяется разницей значений глаголов "жить" и "проживать".    Употреблять - в зависимости от контекста.

ЖИТЬ, живу, живёшь; жил, -ла, жило (с отриц.: не жил, не жила, не жило, не жили и не жил, не жило, не жили); живя; нсв.
1.
Существовать, быть живым. Ж. долго. Жил сто лет. Рыбы не могут ж. без воды. Цветы не могут ж. в темноте. После операции он жил только три дня. //
Вести деятельную жизнь; пользоваться жизнью, наслаждаться ею. Ж. полной, настоящей жизнью.
2. кем-чем.
Быть поглощённым чем-л., увлечённым кем-, чем-л., считать что-л. главным в жизни. Ж. детьми, сыном, семьёй. Ж. наукой, театром, спортом Ж. какой-л. надеждой, ожиданием чего-л., воспоминаниями.
3.
Вести тот или иной образ жизни. Ж. богато. Ж. уединённо. Ж. припеваючи. Ж. холостяком, отшельником. // чем и на что.
Поддерживать своё существование чем-л. Ж. собственным трудом, уроками; ж. на зарплату, на пенсию, на доходы от чего-л. Ж. на чужой счёт.
4.
Пребывать, проживать где-л. Ж. в гостинице, общежитии. Ж. в городе, деревне, за границей. Ж. в двухкомнатной квартире. //
Обитать где-л., населять что-л.; водиться где-л. (о животных). Медведь зимой живёт в берлоге. В нашем пруду живут караси. //

Вести жизнь общую с кем-л., среди кого-л.; проживать совместно. Ж. с женой, с мужем, с матерью, с сыном, с семьёй. Ж. вдвоём в одной комнате. // (с предлогом в и предлож. падежом мн. числа или с тв. падежом ед. числа сущ., обозначающего род занятий). Устар.
Работать, служить в качестве кого-л., проживая в доме хозяина. Ж. в кухарках, в дворниках.
5. с кем. Разг.
Находиться с кем-л. в любовной связи. Живёт с чужой женой.
6.
Быть, находиться, иметься. Во мне живёт уверенность, что всё уладится. ◊ Жить своим умом.
Быть самостоятельным, независимым в решении жизненных вопросов, в своих поступках. Жить чужим умом.
Не проявлять самостоятельности в решении жизненных вопросов, прибегать к авторитетам. Велеть (приказать) долго жить.
Умереть. (За) здорово живёшь (см. 2. Здорово). Как живёте-можете? (см. 1. Мочь).

======

ПРОЖИВАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; нсв.
1.
к Прожить.
2. где.
Иметь какое-л. место постоянного жительства. П. в съёмной квартире по новому адресу. П. по Спасскому переулку, дом два. < Проживание, -я; ср. Адрес проживания.

ПРОЖИТЬ, -живу, -живёшь; прожил, -ла, -ло и (разг.) прожил, -ло; прожитый; -жит, -а, -о и (устар.) прожитый; -жит, -а, -о; св.
1.
Просуществовать, пробыть живым какое-л. время. П. восемьдесят лет. После операции не прожил и года.
2.
Пробыть какое-л. время, живя где-л. или каким-л. образом. П. месяц в деревне. П. несколько лет за границей. Всю жизнь прожил в центре города. //
Пробыть в каких-л. отношениях (супружеских, деловых, дружеских)
какое-л. время. Прожили вместе двадцать лет. И года не прожили - разошлись. П. бок о бок всю молодость.
3.
Поддержать своё существование каким-л. образом, обойтись какими-л. средствами. П. бы до получки. Ничего, как-нибудь проживём! На такую зарплату не проживёшь. Без специальности п. трудно.
4. что.
Издержать, израсходовать, истратить на жизнь, существование. П. все деньги, все сбережения, все средства. П. всю зарплату за неделю. < Проживать (см.). Проживаться, -ается; страд. (4 зн.). Проживание, -я; ср. (2, 4 зн.). Временное п. в общежитии. П. денег.

========

©Кузнецов

Если в двух словах, "проживать" имеет только два значения, одно из которых в той или иной степени сводится к "просуществовать" какой-то отрезок времени, другое - связано с местом постоянного жительства (оно обычно и употребляется).
"Жить" - неизмеримо богаче.
Это и определяет разницу в значениях причастий.